# Recall an activity

Tags: java, android, json

I want to recall an activity after 12 minutes whole the times who get my JSON but i don't know how use timertask and timershedule can you help me please? 
I try this but isn't work 
my program:

```
public class recuperationJson extends AppCompatActivity implements getData.ReturnValue {
private getData data;
private TextView t;
private String json_string;
private String json_url = "http://192.168.0.14/projet/php/fichier.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    data = new getData(json_url);
    data.setReturnListener(this);
    data.execute((Void) null);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Testing(), 0,5000);
}

@Override
public String renvoyerValeurString(String valeurARenvoyer) {
    data = null;
    //Ici je récupère directement mon json contenu dans la variable valeurARenvoyer
    json_string = valeurARenvoyer;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Accueil.class);
    intent.putExtra("json_data", json_string);
    startActivity(intent);
   // Toast.makeText(this, json_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return json_string;
}
public class Testing extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(recuperationJson.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
              Process: com.suprem.projetfinal, PID: 3196
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:344)
                  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:100)
                  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
                  at com.suprem.projetfinal.recuperationJson$Testing$override.run(recuperationJson.java:48)
                  at com.suprem.projetfinal.recuperationJson$Testing$override.access$dispatch(recuperationJson.java)
                  at com.suprem.projetfinal.recuperationJson$Testing.run(recuperationJson.java:0)
                  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: You just want to parse or get big data which lasts 12 minutes? Or run a code after 12 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. In calling class schedule your timer.

```
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Testing(), 0,5000);
```

in the testing class perform your activity

```
      import java.util.TimerTask;


      public class Testing extends TimerTask
      {

     public void run()
     {
      //your task here
     }
     }
```

Timer doesn't work once server get shutdown or restart. Better to use quartz.

Comment: I edit my post with your method but isn't work cause of the thread can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods come up with my mind.

**1 - Handler**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        System.out.println("RUN AFTER 12 minutes");

     }
 }, 12*60*1000);
```

**2 - AlarmManager**

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override public void onReceive( Context context, Intent _ )
            {
               System.out.println("RUN AFTER 12 minutes");
                context.unregisterReceiver( this ); 
            }
        };

        registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter("message") );

        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("message"), 0 );
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

        // set alarm to fire
        manager.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60*1000*12, pintent );
```